# Unable share windows folder VM Player

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player, shared-folders

Using VM Player 4.06, Ubuntu 14.04, Windows 7
In the  VM setting, I have setup the shared folder (and enabled them) - **but I can't browse to it**.

I go Browse network - I see both 'My laptop' and 'Windows Network'. 
Per docs if I browse Windows Network I should see my shared folder - but I see nothing at all.

I can browse my laptop and see everything,  can 'copy' but unable to paste onto my VM (Ubuntu)- likely could be permissions n stuff.

I thought this was some out of the box functionality and would work 'seamlessly'. Am I doing something wrong?

Based on [some other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580319/enabling-shared-folders-with-open-vm-tools) I tried

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools-dkms
mkdir /mnt/hgfs
/usr/bin/vmware-vmblock-fuse /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
:~$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hgfs/Shared
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/hgfs/Shared’: Function not implemented
```

How do I fix this?

Also the next step is to share

```
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/Share /mnt/hgfs/Share
```

**What is the syntax for this** I have shared my windows folder c:\VM-Shared

2.It seems there are some patches to be done
[Files missing in /mnt/hgfs on Ubuntu VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591664/files-missing-in-mnt-hgfs-on-ubuntu-vm)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
$ cd vmware-tools-patches
$ sudo ./patched-open-vm-tools.sh
```

Did this but still does not work.

```
$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host /usr/share/win7share
```

The above command does not work - I just get how to use response.
[Per VMware docs it should work](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html)
(I had created win7share directory earlier)

So my problem is not solved. And a very serious new problem has got created. **Cant cut-n-paste between my lost (laptop) and my VM.** This is ahuge problem - I may have to ininstall these tools I just installed. Will post a separte question on this.

Answer (score 0):

My mount syntax was wrong, the correct syntax is:
$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs **.host:/** /usr/share/win7share

**this works**

$cd /usr/share/win7share 
shows my 2 shared windows folders.

**Need to still solve the cut-n-paste problem** (I am totally doomed without it)